How do I remove or delete an object inside a function?
I want to make a simple delete function in Python which should remove any reference and delete the object. This can be used to remove unused simulated objects:
import numpy as np

class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        # 8GB of data
        self.data = np.random.randint(0, 1, 1000*1000*1000)
        self.HP = 5

def attack(unit):

    unit.HP -= 10

    if unit.HP <= 0:
        # Here we remove all the reference to the unit
        """
        Some codes on removing references
        """

        del unit

unit = Unit()

attack(unit)

print(unit.data)  #  <- this should not be accessible

input('Press any key to exit...')

But this would not work:
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
Press any key to exit...

Unit can be defined in global or local scope, depending on the game environment. Since there is no reference to this object, the reference counter is zero so the garbage collector should release it from memory. But how can I do this explicitly inside a function?
On the other hand, if I call del outside the function I can release it from memory:
import numpy as np

class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        # 8GB of data
        self.data = np.random.randint(0, 1, 1000*1000*1000)
        self.HP = 5

def attack(unit):

    unit.HP -= 10

    if unit.HP <= 0:
        # Here we remove all the reference to the unit
        """
        Some codes on removing references
        """

        del unit

unit = Unit()

del unit

print(unit.data)  #  <- this should not be accessible

input('Press any key to exit...')

This gives:
    print(unit.data)  #  <- this should be not accessible
          ^^^^
NameError: name 'unit' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Unit'?

Then it does not use 8GB of memory anymore.

you cannot delete an object directly in Python. Python is a garbage collected language, and in CPython, the basic garbage collection strategy is reference counting.

"Since there is no reference to this unit object, the counted reference number is zero, so the garbage collector should release this from the memory. " there is a reference to this objecct. It is in the global namespace, so the object won't be garbage collected.

Then is there any way to remove global reference? More generally, is there general way to remove all the references?

Does this answer your question? Delete object instance from class function in python

The same way you should always handle this: organize your code to not leave unused references around. Again, you cannot delete an object directly

@juanpa.arrivillaga If there is no reference to the unit, then garbage collector release it from the memory, so 8GB memory is released if we just call del unit in global scope. So I think if the del is called within the same scope as unit defined, then we can delete it. @JonSG I saw that, but basically it says "it is not possible".

The process may still hold on to that memory, but it will be available.

@SeungHyeonYu objects don't have a scope. The fact that the unit was defined in the global scope originally doesn't guarantee you haven't made a reference elsewhere. Again, this is fundamentally about how you organize your program.

Don't use the global scope as a container. Put units you care about in an explicit list, dict, etc, and remove objects from that container as necessary.

@juanpa.arrivillaga That's why I want to make delete function. It will remove all the references to the unit. If it is not possible, that means, it is very hard to releasing memory of many dead units (which have huge amount of attributes)... @chepner This is just one example that can delete an object and release it from the memory.

@SeungHyeonYu no, it isn't difficult, you simply organize your program reasonably (e.g. by using the approach chepner suggested).  This is how garbage-collected languages work.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Then in this example, can you let me know what is the good way of organizing the program for making units and attacking and handle dead units with very simple example?

If your object is large and you want to release all its memory, delete all its attributes. The memory of the container object will be negligible.

Aside of garbage collection, which may or may not take place, the effect of del is to remove the binding of the object name in the current local or global namespace, whichever applies.
So trying to delete the object locally only affects the local namespace and preserves the global binding, as in:
l = [1, 2, 3]
def remove(l):
    # l has local scope here
    del l
    try:
        l
    except NameError:
        print("l does not exist (locally) any longer")

remove(l)
l does not exist (locally) any longer

print(l)
[1, 2, 3]

However, in the global case you have
l = [1, 2, 3]
def remove():
    global l
    del l

print(l)
[1, 2, 3]

remove()
print(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'l' is not defined

Bottom line being you might use globals everywhere to achieve your goal but this may not be the best coding practice

In python, when objects are passed to a function, they are passed by reference, so the function receives a local copy of the reference to the object, not the actual object itself. Therefore, if you delete the reference inside the function, you're only deleting the local reference, not the original reference in the global scope. So, you can pass the variable (object) name, get the corresponding object from the global scope and delete it, like this:
def attack(unit, obj_name):
    
    unit.HP -= 10
    
    if unit.HP <= 0:
        # Here we remove all the reference to the unit
        """
        Some codes on removing references
        """
        
        del globals()[obj_name]

unit = Unit()

attack(unit, "unit")



another_unit = Unit()

attack(another_unit, "another_unit")

If you don't want to pass variable (object) name, than you will need to iterate through all objects of global scope and compare the ids, if matched, than delete, like this:
def attack(unit):
    
    unit.HP -= 10
    
    if unit.HP <= 0:
        # Here we remove all the reference to the unit
        """
        Some codes on removing references
        """
        
        for obj_name, obj in list(globals().items()):
            if id(obj) == id(unit):
                del globals()[obj_name]

unit = Unit()

attack(unit)

As separate functions:
def delete_instance(instance):
    for obj_name, obj in list(globals().items()):
        if id(obj) == id(instance):
            del globals()[obj_name]


def delete_instance_by_name(variable_name):
    del globals()[variable_name]

